# drupal_get_form of custom content types

Tags: forms, nodes

I am wracking my brain to try to figure out how to retrieve a custom content type's edit form programatically.

For example, I created a content type called "address", and have this:

```
$form = drupal_get_form("address_node_form");
```

But it does not work. I get back this warning:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First
>   argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'node_form' was given in
>   drupal_retrieve_form() (line 771 of
>   /home/richardp/public_html/drupal7/d7/includes/form.inc).

I know that in D6 you also had to include an object where you specify the type, but I have tried this and it still doesn't work.

When I try simply `$x = node_add("page");` I get a white screen of death, presumably because I ran into a PHP error.

Am I supposed to be including a file first or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code to display the Edit Form in Node View page:

```
<?php
// modules/custom/custom.module

function custom_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $node = $vars['node'];
    $form = drupal_get_form('mytype_node_form', $node);
    $vars['content']['edit_form'] = $form;
}
?>
```

Notes:

1. You need to replace custom with your module's name and mytype with
   the machine-readable name of your content-type.
2. I just used a clone of $vars['node'] to prevent probable problems
   caused by the fact that $vars is passed by reference; though it
   might not be necessary.

Comment: Good answer...the clone is unnecessary though